# Umbraco Back Office content search fails on I - i character

Tags: lucene, umbraco, culture, turkish, examine

Umbraco back office search fails on some Turkish characters. Some of them (Ç-Ş etc) works correctly. However the I stands for little ı and İ is for i.

We have problem on I and İ characters. Using standart InternalIndexSet for back office with the initial settings.

Should I override some class or can I handle it with a quick trick on config files.

Thanks for your help,

Comment: This thread may be helpful: https://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/extending-umbraco/16396-Examine-and-accents-for-portuguese-language

Comment: Hi Mark I've tried it, however it didn't worked for me. When i search content , which's name contains "Seçim", with keyword "Seçi" I get no result.But when I use "Seçİ" as a keyword, I get results. It is not about ç character. The letter 'I' makes problem for me.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm  not an Examine expert, have you asked your question on our.umbraco.org? I think there might be some people that are able to help you

Comment: Thank you Mark, I analysed the cource code and probably it does not use the lucene engine. I will post this question to our.umbraco. Have a nice day